# wcf and multicore

Tags: wcf, performance, multicore, nic

I have a wcf service that will be running on a multicore system, with multiple NIC cards. Do I need to do anything in order to take full advantage of the cores? Do I need to run multiple instances of the service? Or will .NET automagically handle everything for me?

Thanks!!

Comment: I believe the answer to this question might depend on your anticipated hosting configuration (Self-hosted, Hosted in a Windows service, Hosted in IIS)

Comment: Thanks, Dirk. This app is a big ball-of-mud of code that I inherited about 6 months ago, and I am also new to WCF. I know that it isn't hosted in IIS, because we are using NetTcpBindings. How can I tell if it is self-hosted, or hosted in a windows service? And how does this affect multi-core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an article discussing [performance settings](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/wcf-improve-performance-with-greater-concurrency/) in WCF you may consider wrt. concurrency.

Comment: Just watch the defaults on queued services (i.e. services that read from MSMQ) I typically set those to one. High concurrency here leads to many failures due to locks.